# Does not match name having space in it Django Python

Tags: python

```
try:
    version_number = request.json['version_number']
    name = request.json['dispensary_name']
    name = str(name)
    if version_number == 1.0:
       if Dispensary.objects.filter(name__iexact=name).exists():
           return {SUCCESS: False, MESSAGE: 'Dispensary name already exists.'}
```

Does not match name having space in it.What should I do for this.

Comment: use `str.strip()`?

Comment: Can you give example of the strings?

Comment: Example :  MELLOW CANNABIS, Herbal Relief Collective